# Regex to match @ followed by square brackets containing a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to parse a pattern similar to this using javascript:

```
@[10] or @[15]
```

With all my efforts, I came up with this:

```
@\\[(.*?)\\]
```

This pattern works fine but the problem is it matches anything b/w those square brackets. I want it to match only numbers. I tried these too:

```
@\\[(0-9)+\\]
```

and

```
@\\[([(0-9)+])\\]
```

But these match nothing.

Also, I want to match only pattern which are complete words and not part of a word in the string. i.e. should contain spaces both side if its not starting or ending the script. That means it should not match phrase like this:

```
abxdcs@[13]fsfs
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doubling the backslashes?  Doubled, they match stuff like `@\+)\]` unless your pattern is in a string.

Comment: Single slashes didn't seem to be working. Doubled are working fine at some level. I am pretty new to this stuff..

Comment: `@\[[0-9]*\]` Example: http://regexr.com?3572f  If possible, can you give us some of your JavaScript code?  @cHao is correct, `\\ ` would be an escaped `\ `. *Note* StackOverflow escapes with those too.  Added a space to the end for easier results.

Comment: cHao, in languages in which regexes are generated from string literals instead of directly from regex literals, there's an extra level of character escaping, so you need double backslashes. For example, the string literal `"\\d"` gives the string `\d`, hence the regex `/\d/`. (I'm talking about things like `\d`. For newline characters etc it's probably just a single backslash, since newlines are not a regex special character.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex:

```
/(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g
```

It will match if the pattern (`@[number]`) is not a part of a word. Should contain spaces both sides if its not starting or ending the string.

It uses groups, so if need the digits, use the group 1.

[**Testing code (click here for demo):**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJ7jT/2/)

```
console.log(/(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g.test("@[10]")); // true
console.log(/(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g.test("@[15]")); // true
console.log(/(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g.test("abxdcs@[13]fsfs")); // false
console.log(/(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g.test("abxdcs @[13] fsfs")); // true

var r1 = /(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g
var match = r1.exec("@[10]");
console.log(match[1]); // 10

var r2 = /(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g
var match2 = r2.exec("abxdcs @[13] fsfs");
console.log(match2[1]); // 13

var r3 = /(?:^|\s)@\[([0-9]+)\](?=$|\s)/g
var match3;
while (match3 = r3.exec("@[111] @[222]")) {
    console.log(match3[1]);
}
// while's output: 
// 111
// 222
```

Comment: This should work, as long as you don't need to capture the numbers.

Comment: Actually, I didn't meant by the string should start or end by the pattern. I meant this pattern should not be a part of a word. Should contain spaces both sides if its not starting or ending the string.

Comment: This works almost fine. Except, when there are multiple mentions in a string, its creating problem. Say if the string is "hello @[12] world @[13]", its working fine, but when I am matching "@[12] @[13]", its only matching @[12].

Comment: @Sourabh ok, it really was not supposed to get more than one. Let me adapt.

Comment: Well, its getting more than one but only when there exists something between them. Other wise its only taking the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but you need to use square brackets:

```
@\[[0-9]+\]
```

Or, a shorter version:

```
@\[\d+\]
```

The reason you need those slashes is to "escape" the square bracket. Usually they are used for denoting a "[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)".

`[0-9]` creates a character class which matches exactly one digit in the range of 0 to 9. Adding the `+` changes the meaning to "one or more". `\d` is just shorthand for `[0-9]`.

Of course, the backslash character is also used to escape characters inside of a javascript string, which is why you must escape them. So:

**javascript**

```
"@\\[\\d+\\]"
```

turns into:

**regex**

```
@\[\d+\]
```

which is used to match:

> `@` a literal "@" symbol
>   `\[` a literal "[" symbol
>   `\d+` one or more digits (nearly identical to `[0-9]+`)
>   `\]` a literal "]" symbol

I say that `\d` is *nearly* identical to `[0-9]` because, in some regex flavors ([including .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#DigitCharacter)), `\d` will actually match numeric digits from other cultures in addition to 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so many characters inside the character class. More importantly, you put the + in the wrong place. Try this: `@\\[([0-9]+)\\]`.